# process exit code 127 while running a bash script by java service in docker

Tags: java, bash, docker, process

I am running this script from java code in docker and exit code of the process is 127.

`process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands); // commands is an array with script name and other variables defined in the script.
process.waitFor();`

`openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in $ENCRYPTED_TARBALL -out $OUTPUT_TAR -K $password`

I made sure that openssl is installed in docker and script, $ENCRYPTED_TARBALL and $OUTPUT_TAR are accessible. $OUTPUT_TAR file should be created if the script execution is successful.

Comment: Are you sure $PATH is set correctly?

Comment: Please give the output of `echo $PATH` & `which openssl`. Also give the exact error printed in the console.

Comment: It does not throw any error, I have the process status code printed in the logs as 127.

Comment: First of all, have you tried to run the same command from the shell (if you can run it without the docker)? 127 is the usual return code when a program fails to execute, for instance if libraries can not be loaded. This happens typically if you setup a LD_LIBRARY_PATH and one of its libs conflicts with the libs that `openssl` is supposed to run with. If your command works from the shell, please run `ldd /usr/bin/openssl` both from the shell and from the docker and look for any difference between the two.

Comment: I ran it without docker and it works fine. I had another script running by java application with openssl to generate password which is working fine.