# Running Dockerfile with bash script

Tags: windows, bash, dockerfile

Hi I'm trying to run this following Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ADD install /
RUN chmod u+x /install
RUN /install
ENV PATH /root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
CMD ["ipython"]
```

combined with this bash script

```bash
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install -y bzip2 gcc git htop screen vim wget
apt-get upgrade -y bashapt-get clean
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O Miniconda.sh
bash Miniconda.sh -b
rm -rf Miniconda.sh
export PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
conda update -y conda python
conda install -y pandas
conda install -y ipython
```

The Dockerfile and the bash script are in the same folder, really not sure what I'm doing wrong here. This is the error I'm getting:

```bash
 $ docker build -t py4fi:basic .
[+] Building 0.5s (8/8) FINISHED                             
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 31B                     0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                       0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                         0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubu  0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                       0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 434B                       0.0s 
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04           0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/4] ADD install /                          0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] RUN chmod u+x /install                 0.0s 
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN /install                            0.4s 
------                                                       
 > [4/4] RUN /install:
#8 0.416 /bin/sh: 1: /install: not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /install]: exit code: 127
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: To see if it makes any difference, can you try `RUN bash /install` instead of `RUN /install`? That should help see if it's some kind of permission issue. I'd also add `RUN ls -l /install` just after the chmod, to see of the chmod worked as it should have.

Comment: Thanks, will try this when back at my computer!

Comment: But nevermind: I just ran your Dockerfile as is, and it works for me, so I cannot reproduce your problem. Things that might help troubleshoot: What OS are you running on? What version of Docker are you using? Anything else stands out in your setup?

Comment: Oh really? I’m running Windows 11 and the latest Docker version (just installed it)

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. My Docker is not quite up to date. I would not expect that to make a difference here, but if someone here on Win 11 can try too, maybe someone else can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Just tried again with the latest version of Docker, and it works fine too.

Comment: so weird, for me it's not working. I get Docker running now if I comment out the RUN /install part, but then obvioulsy the script doesn't get executed and I have to do everything manually. 

Just checked my Docker it's: 

Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701

Comment: here at the end someone suggests that it may be a visual studio code thing and that adding this mentioned "end of the line" extension would fix it. Unfortunately that extension is no longer available to try. On the other hand if I try it outside VSCode from terminal I get the same errors so probably not that either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423272/process-exit-code-127-while-running-a-bash-script-by-java-service-in-docker

Comment: Ah, yes, that's it! On Linux, a bash script must have Linux-style newline characters, if it has CRLF it will fail. Does your VSCode show a little "CRLF" at the lower right corner or in the status bar? Click it and select "LF" instead and save the install script again, that will probably get things working for you. I think it's builtin to VSCode now, but if not I'm sure there are multiple extensions available to do it. And there are multiple tools outside vscode that will convert for you, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### TL;DR

On all platforms, even containerized, Bash scripts must have Unix-style line endings (LF), except in some cases on Windows, like with sufficiently recent versions Git Bash.

##### Details

I just reproduced your exact error message when I saved the `install` file with CRLF line endings on my computer.

On Windows, Git-Bash is patched to tolerate Windows-style CRLF line endings, but on all other platforms Bash only accepts Unix-style LF line endings. When you run `install` in the docker build, it's using the Bash that is distributed with your base image, where it ends up looking for (and not finding) `/bin/bash\0x0D` instead of `/bin/bash`.

The solution is simple, you have to convert the newlines to LF for the `install` file. (The Dockerfile can have either line endings.) On my computer, VSCode has a `CRLF` showing at the right of the status bar (see my screen snip below), which I can click to change to `LF` and save the file again with Unix line endings.

Change: [image]

To: [image]